# Predicting topics for customer reviews based on topics mapped to n-grams?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embeddings, lda

I have a large number of unlabelled customer review data(text column) and my objective is to classify each review to a particular topic.
[image: Customer_review_data]

Also I have a list of unigrams,bigrams and trigrams(not a part of the customer review data) where each n-gram(word column) is tagged with a particular topic(topic column).

[image: n-gram topic mapping data]

Is there a way to classify the customer reviews to the topics associated with the n-grams? 
I am mostly thinking in terms of Word2Vec and Doc2Vec approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the Facebook starspace library - their examples are similar but with suggesting Facebook pages and hashtags.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/StarSpace